# GData Objective-C Client SVN could not be checked out

Tags: objective-c, ios, gdata

I tried to checkout the GData for Obejctive-C client (found the link from here: http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/checkout), but it kept telling me that revision is non-existent. I also tried different tools and methods. But none of that worked. If you have any idea about this problem, please do let me know.

Comment: Did you try checking it out using Xcode's integrated client, or did you run your checkout from the command line? The command line checkout worked fine for me: `svn checkout http://gdata-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ gdata-objectivec-client-read-only`.

Comment: Hi @dasblinkenlight when I run svn in terminal, it told me that svn command not found.

Comment: You may want to install subversion separately (older Xcode used to make subversion available from the command line, I do not know about the current version). My `svn` runs from `/opt/subversion/bin/`, see if you have this directory on your system, and if it's there, try `/opt/subversion/bin/svn checkout http://...and so on...` command instead. Make sure that you run it in the parent directory of where you'd like the checked out code to reside.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thanks a lot! I just installed the command line tool in Xcode, and it did the job!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong URL. open *Terminal* and do this:

```
svn checkout http://gdata-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ gdata-objectivec-client-read-only
```